# Refreshing a URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, cpanel

We have built an application with AngularJS, it is currently hosted on a shared cPanel hosting. However, whenever we do a refresh on any page we are at with ? in the url. It will break.

I have read extensively on Stackoverflow, I understand it is because of the browser doesn't know which page to load and hence we need to set the base url in the header. We tried setting the base url and did some htaccess settings but it is still not working.

Try to click on any link from the website and refresh that page. You will notice it failed to work.

Any kind soul can point us to the right directions on how we can solve this?

Edit 1:
I have these in htaccess and notice the only url with ? will refuse to load correct.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api

# otherwise forward it to index.html 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/* /index.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue didn't come from htaccess but the folder name. For instance,

```
config(function($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider.state('search', {
url: '/search?page&loc&seaters&owner&min_price&max_price',
```

The problem is when our folder is also call search, Apache will attempt to go to search folder first (due to the htaccess) and because they can find the folder, it will read the folder directory.

We fixed it by naming the folder example: search-html and change all the templateUrl required to search-html and it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the Issue but its not showing any # tag in the URL as mentioned. Can you please explain in details.

Comment: Have you tried this 
.config(function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})

Comment: Yes, I did. That helped to remove the # but not solve the refresh issue,